# How do I normalize the data sets in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a data set of 2109, 10885 and 1109 instances with 22 attributes. I applied some methods to find the dataset's performance, but I want to find the performance of these data sets on its normalized data. I tried to find out how to normalize data but I couldn't find anything.

How can I learn how to normalize data sets in MATLAB? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Could you post the code for others to help you?

Comment: You can try what is known as standardizing your data.  This is usually done by taking each feature / attribute and normalizing them so there is zero mean and unit variance.  Check out the post I marked as duplicate for more details.  Good luck!